# Symmetrically $3d$ embeddable graphs with high girth

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, 3d, symmetry

Let a symmetrically $3d$ embeddable graph be a graph that can be embedded into $3d$ so that the embedding is arc-transitive, which means that every vertex-edge pair with the vertex incident to the edge can be mapped to any other vertex-edge pair using a symmetry of $3d$ space in such a way that every vertex maps to a vertex and every edge maps to an edge. What is the highest girth such a finite cubic graph can have? What is the highest girth such a cubic infinite graph can have, with the additional constraint that there must be a bounded distance between vertices?

The dodecahedron has girth $5$, and that is the highest girth that I know of for such a finite graph. The Laves graph is infinite and has a girth of $10$. Is an infinite tree possible? What if the graphs don't need to be cubic but have a degree greater than $2$? What if the minimum distance between vertices has to be the length of an edge?

[Post on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435407/symmetrically-3d-embeddable-graphs-with-high-girth)

Comment: Do you count the [cubitruncated cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubitruncated_cuboctahedron) as an embedding?

Comment: Yes, but it is not arc-transitive.

Comment: Oh, true, at some point I accidentally started thinking about vertex transitivity instead. Too bad, because it has girth 6.

Comment: An infinite cubic tree is impossible even without the symmetry constraint, if we want to avoid arbitrarily-close vertices. If all distances between vertices are at least $\epsilon$, the spheres of radius $\frac\epsilon2$ around vertices are disjoint, so there are at most $(\frac{2r}\epsilon)^3$ vertices within graph distance $r$ of a fixed vertex $v$. There are $3\cdot2^{r-1}$ paths of length $r$ starting at $v$, so as soon as $3\cdot2^{r-1}>(\frac{2r}\epsilon)^3$, there is a cycle of length at most $2r$, because two of these paths lead to the same destination.

Comment: A modified argument that considers vertices with graph distance less than $r$ as well proves that the "minimum distance = edge" case has girth at most 24.